# XSL Browser Issue

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt, browser, safari

I'm able to run in firefox but not able to do it in Chrome or Safari. I want it to run in all three browsers

Chrome Version - 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Ran `open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=$HOME/fakeChromeDir` to run xsl

Safari Version - 13.0.4 (14608.4.9.1.4)
Checked Disable Local File Restrictions and Cross-Origin Restrictions

Firefox Version - 68.4.2esr (64 bit)
Set to privacy.file_unique_origin;false and security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy;false

If I replace the below code in XSL

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".[*/*]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select=".[* and not(*/*)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('table-group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name()))[1])]" mode="merge-groups"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[*/*]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="*[* and not(*/*)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('table-group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name()))[1])]" mode="merge-groups"/>
```

It works in all browsers but I want to maintain the oder of tables as in xml. So, I'm using a for loop.

My XML file

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'utf-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformer.xsl" ?>
<group1>
    <item1>val1</item1>
    <item2>val2</item2>
    <group2>
        <item3>val3</item3>
        <item4>val4</item4>
        <group3>
            <item5>val5</item5>
        </group3>
    </group2>
    <group2>
        <item3>val6</item3>
        <item4>val7</item4>
        <group3>
            <item5>val8</item5>
        </group3>
    </group2>
    <group4>
        <item6>val9</item6>
        <item7>val10</item7>
    </group4>
    <group4>
        <item6>val11</item6>
        <item7>val12</item7>
    </group4>
</group1>
```

My Xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:key name="table-group"
    match="*[* and not(*/*)]"
    use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name())"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <div>
      <h4><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></h4>
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]" mode="header"/>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]"/>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".[*/*]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select=".[* and not(*/*)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('table-group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name()))[1])]" mode="merge-groups"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]" mode="header">
      <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
      <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="merge-groups">
    <div>
      <h4><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></h4>
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]" mode="header"/>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('table-group', concat(generate-id(..), '|', local-name()))" mode="row"/>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
      <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <title>Diagnostic Report</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What exactly happens "in Chrome or Safari", which error exactly (use F12 to open the web developer tools and check the error console) or which wrong result do you get?

Comment: It shows no error in both of them @MartinHonnen when viewed through inspector tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think XPath 1 has a restriction that a predicate cannot be applied to the abbreviated form `.` but you should be able to replace it by `self::node()` so use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="self::node()[*/*]"/>`. Make the same change for other place where you try to use `.[predicate]`.